# Excluding 'that' and 'have' in "We are confident (that) this will be the best treatment you (have) ever experienced"

Tags: conjunctions, relative-pronouns, content-clauses, elision

When you are promoting a product that the consumer has not used yet, would you include or exclude the words between parentheses in the phrase below? I’m not a native English speaker, and the more I think it over, the more I start to doubt it. Google's results made me doubt even more. :) Would love to hear it from one of you experts to be 100% sure.

The sentence:

> We are confident **(that)** this will be the best treatment you **(have)** ever experienced.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Leaving out the "have", making it "the best treatment you ever experienced", makes it feel very informal.  I might speak that way to a friend, but I wouldn't write it in promotional material.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a native AmE speaker:

> We are confident this will be the best treatment you **have** ever experienced.

The **that** is unnecessary and makes the first part of your statement feel **bulky**.

**Have ever** is needed to go with **experienced** meaning to-date, this will **be the best**.

If you changed your sentence to

> ...the best treatment you **ever** experience.

That would include both past and **any possible future treatments**.

Comment: Thanks for your time and clear answer Peter. Have a great day!